# nginx show 502 bad gateway

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

502 Bad gateway error.
Error log and nginx configure are as follows.
Anything wrong with that?

> [error] 7660#0: *10 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while
>   connecting to upstream, client: 40.83.126.181, server: 127.0.0.1,
>   request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host:
>   "www.mysite.com"

nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024; 
}


http{

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  127.0.0.1;

        location / {
            root   /www;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

    }


    include vhost/*.conf; 
}
```

vhosts/home.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.mysite.com
    #charset utf-8;
    access_log  /www/host.access.log;
    error_log   /www/error.log;
    root /www;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
           rewrite  ^/(.*)$  /index.php/$1  last;
           break;
        }
    }
    location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$ {
        expires 100d;
    }
    location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$ {
        expires 30d;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    location ~ \.php(/|$) {
        root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please check your php-fpm is running or you are using socket as unix path.

Answer (score 1):

Run php-fpm and make sure that nginx and php-fpm are under the same user(group),and the problem solved.